# Why I don't see the "join pvp" option in cruel difficulty?

Tags: path-of-exile

In normal difficulty, the pvp queueing option was in act 2, when you speak to Greust, but now in cruel difficulty I just don't see it.

Depending on the difficulty, where can I join pvp matches?

Answer (score 1):

**Theory:**

In PoE there are two PvP "modes":

- Low-level PvP, with a maximum player level of 28
- High-level PvP, without a maximum player level

You can access the low-level PvP queues from Greust in normal Act 2 or the Event noticeboard in Act 3.
The high-level PvP queues can be accessed from the Event noticeboards, which are located in every town (except normal Act 1).
You should be able to get into the high-level PvP from the Event Noticeboard in cruel Act 2, but don't expect to win, you will most likely be matched with a player that is level 80 or above.

There are other options to start PvP matches though:

- right click any player and select "Challenge to Duel"
- The Sarn Arena, in the northern Part of the Act 3 town you can find the Sarn Arena, a PvP Arena that can be entered and exited at will

You can find more information on the different PvP modes [here](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/PvP).

**Reality:**

In Cruel your chances of finding another player that want's to PvP are rather slim.
Random players in town are seldomly interested in PvP and the Cruel Sarn Arena is usually empty.

Your best bet would probably be to ask for a challenger in global chat.

Alternatively you can create a PvP-only character that starts out at level 28 and can only be used to access the Low-Level PvP queus.